# PHONEGAP AJAX pegando ip junto com a url

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache-cordova

Estou fazendo uma simples requisição usando o phonegap:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://mydomain.com/request",
        data: params,
        success: function(result){

        },
        error: function(e, data, status, xhr){

        }
    })
```

Mas ao executar ele execulta a seguinte url:

```
http://<ip>:3000/proxy/http://mydomain.com/request
```

Comment: Todos os proxies estão desligados

Comment: O pessoal comentou no SOzão pra tentar com `phonegap browser run` em vez de `phonegap serve` pra não usar o proxy, não sei se vc conseguiria aplicar ao seu caso.

Comment: Eu estava rodando pelo proprio app desktop, não via linha de comando

Comment: Não tem nenhum lugar de configuração onde eu informo minha base url? para substituir o <ip>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui, simplesmente alterando o `dataType: "json"` para `dataType: "jsonp"`.

Deu outro erro, mas aí que outra questão. Do Jsonp